# Is there any limit on execution time for background sync and message event in serviceWorker?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

For a sync or message event in *serviceWorker* if I pass a **promise** to `event.waitUntil()` that will resolve in 5-7 minutes. Will serviceWorker still will be in running state? From [this](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/o2D4WrmO230) source it's said that execution time for sync event is limited to 3 minutes. Will this restriction apply for message event also? If execution time is limited to 3 minutes, what happens to below code?

```
event.waitUntil(PromiseThatResolvesIn9Minutes().then(someOtherTask));
```

Will `someOtherTask` method executed by serviceWorker if `PromiseThatResolvesIn9Minutes` resolves after 3 minutes?

Comment: I think this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers#Install_and_activate_populating_your_cache) can explain you how the `event.waitUntil()` method work in your code. They provide here a sample code that uses `event.waitUntil()` method then explained the process on how this code works. Unfortunately, there is no any hint here about the time limit for the execution time. For more information, check also this [link](https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/#extendable-event-waituntil-method).

Comment: @KENdi I found the answer. Thanks. [This](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#service-worker-lifetime) documentation says there is a limit on serviceWorker lifetime on special cases. And the current chrome implementation has 3 minute time limit on execution time of events. That time limit applies to message event as well.